# $T(n) = \sqrt n\,T(\sqrt n) + n\log n$

Tags: recursion

I tried to solve this recursion equation with master theory, and it's not working in this way.

How many arrays exist in each step in the recursion tree?

And how can I solve this problem with another way?

Comment: Please look at the definition of a tag before using it: (theta-functions) is something else.

Answer (score 1):

The direct way: consider the change of variable $$S(n)=\frac{T(n)}n-2\log n.$$

Comment: thanks , can u be please more specific?

Comment: Sure: did you try to write $S(n)$ in terms of $S(\sqrt{n})$? If you did, please write here the recursion you got. (A downvoter seems to think this is too much to ask to do.)